# Event is not running

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
const face = document.querySelector('.face');
const con = document.querySelector('.con');

for (let i = 0; i < face.length; i++){
con.addEventListener("click" , () => {
        face[i].style.transform = "translateZ(600px)";       
    });
}
```

I wanted to change a CSS property as you see in the code. But even though the con element is being clicked, no action is happening. The event I have written for con for the action click not running.
Actually there are five face elements in that con element in HTML code.

Comment: The loop is never entered. `querySelector` selects only a single element, you need `querySelectorAll` to select all `.face`s into a iterable NodeList.

Comment: i would temporarily replace the core command, the one within the event. just with a console.log command. now u dont know, if the event is not running or the operation within the even is failing. divide and conquer man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the first problem is that **you want a single element selected with `querySelector` to contain more than one element. Which is impossible, instead you can select all available elements with `querySelectorAll`**.

*Then instead of looping through the index, you can fetch each children so you don't have to select them later.*

Final Code:

```js
const faces = document.querySelectorAll('.face');
const con = document.querySelector('.con');

for (const face of faces){
    con.addEventListener("click" , () => {
        face.style.transform = "translateZ(600px)";       
    });
}
```

*Edit for multi-list error*

```js
const faces = document.querySelectorAll('.face');
const con = document.querySelector('.con');

con.addEventListener("click" , () => {
    for (const face of faces) {
        face.style.transform = "translateZ(600px)";       
    };
});
```

or

```js
const faces = document.querySelectorAll('.face');
const con = document.querySelector('.con');

function transfromFaces () {
    for (const face of faces) {
        face.style.transform = "translateZ(600px)";       
    };
}

con.addEventListener("click", transfromFaces);
```

Comment: Now there's still one more issue, the code attaches multiple event listeners to `.con` element, that's hardly OP's intention. The question is a bit ambiguous, though.

Comment: Thanks, i edited the post for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You did a `querySelector`, if you have five `con`, you have to do :

`const con = document.querySelectorAll('.con')`
or
`const con = document.querySelectorAll('.face')`
if you want to select multiple `face`.